# CSS - box-shadow tricks?

Tags: css, shadow

I have an element above a div that is styled to become oval-shaped.
I want to create a shadow on this div as well as the oval shaped element 
but I want the shadow on the oval-shaped element to be below the div.
I'm using a `box-shadow` in the div as well as the oval.
I dunno if there is a code to crop a certain part on the shadow so that I can satisfy the request xD
The layer sequence would be div-shadow, oval-shadow, div, oval.
for reference, you can check the link below.
http://jsfiddle.net/P4NKg/

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use :

```
position:relative;/* this is what it was meant for on the first place move at screen element  */
top:15px;/*to tune with radius value */
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P4NKg/2/)**

alternative with visual bug is :

```
box-shadow : 0px 15px white,/*to tune with radius value */
        0px 25px RGB(5, 80, 150);/*add tuning to width expected  */
```